# building an array or matrix from stdin

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, stdin

I'm trying to build an **array** / **matrix** from a command given through **stdin**. The command is formatted like this:

```
nameOfArray build numberOfDimensions : dimensionList : valueList
```

Another example:

```
B build 1 : 3 : 4,5,6
```

The command needs to work for up to three dimensions, and I am completely stumped as to how to implement it.

Comment: Something like a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are limited to three dimensions, the problem is easy. We simply treat all the cases as the 3 dimensional case, with height and depth set to one for the lower dimensions.

So we set up the array with malloc() or std::vector::resize() width * height * depth, then read the values in one by one. In C, the job is done. In C++, you might then need to fiddle about to turn your vector into a multi-dimensional matrix class with a nice interface.